# How to fix Object(...) not found while it is declared in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to take a derivative of a double sum function. I am running into this error:

```
Error in deriv.f.1(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha = alpha.vector[1, ]) : 
  object 'L_D_grad' not found
```

I have tried to move the `{}` brackets around, double check if I missed a closing/opening bracket, if I have extra opening/closing bracket. However, the error still exists.

```
# Generate Sample Data
gen.sample <- function(n){
  x <- rnorm(n,5,10)
  y <- ifelse(x < 2.843,1,-1)
  return(data.frame(x,y))
}
##
deriv.f.1 <- function(X,y,alpha){
  N <- length(X)
  L_D_grad < numeric(N)
  xy.alpha.sum <- numeric(N)
  for(k in 1:N){
    for(l in 1:N){
      if(l == k){
        xy.alpha.sum[l] = 0}  
      else{
        xy.alpha.sum[l] <- alpha[l]*y[k]*y[l]*X[k]*X[l]}
      }
  L_D_grad[k] <- 1 - sum(xy.alpha.sum) - alpha[k]*(y[k])^2*(X[k])^2
  }
  return(L_D_grad)
}
## Illustration

set.seed(4997)
options(digits = 4,scipen = -4)
sample.data <- gen.sample(n=N)
X.data <- sample.data$x
y.vec <- sample.data$y

alpha.vector <- matrix(rep(seq(from=-5,to = 5, length.out = N),N*N),
                       ncol = N, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
alpha_vec <- alpha.vector[1,]
deriv.f.1(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha_vec)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
# Generate Sample Data
gen.sample <- function(n){
  x <- rnorm(n,5,10)
  y <- ifelse(x < 2.843,1,-1)
  return(data.frame(x,y))
}
##
deriv.f.1 <- function(X,y,alpha){
  N <- length(X)
  L_D_grad <- numeric(N)
  xy.alpha.sum <- numeric(N)
  for(k in 1:N){
    for(l in 1:N){
      if(l == k){
        xy.alpha.sum[l] = 0}  
      else{
        xy.alpha.sum[l] <- alpha[l]*y[k]*y[l]*X[k]*X[l]}
    }
    L_D_grad[k] <- 1 - sum(xy.alpha.sum) - alpha[k]*(y[k])^2*(X[k])^2
  }
  return(L_D_grad)
}
## Illustration

set.seed(4997)
options(digits = 4,scipen = -4)
N=10
sample.data <- gen.sample(n=N)
X.data <- sample.data$x
y.vec <- sample.data$y

alpha.vector <- matrix(rep(seq(from=-5,to = 5, length.out = N),N*N),
                       ncol = N, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
alpha_vec <- alpha.vector[1,]
deriv.f.1(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha_vec)
```

Where:

```
#sample.data
#x  y
#1  -5.303e+00  1
#2   1.493e+01 -1
#3   9.797e+00 -1
#4   1.991e+01 -1
#5  -1.454e+01  1
#6   1.423e+01 -1
#7   1.025e+01 -1
#8   5.455e+00 -1
#9   3.719e+00 -1
#10  2.021e+01 -1
```

And  `deriv.f.1(X = X.data, y = y.vec, alpha =  alpha_vec)`

```
# -1.271e+01 -3.759e+01 -2.432e+01 -5.046e+01 -3.659e+01 -3.577e+01 -2.548e+01 -1.310e+01
# -8.612e+00 -5.123e+01
```

I made two changes:

1. Assign `N` a value: `N=10`
2. Correct assignment form `L_D_grad`: `L_D_grad <- numeric(N)`

Comment: Yes, you were assigned `L_D_grad < numeric(N)`. You just need change `<` for `<-`

Comment: Did you know how many stupid I have made since I started this project on my own?Countless! Thanks brother!